# Access Rails env variable from Angular Controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, environment-variables

I have the following module called EnvConfigurationService,js.erb:

```
#../angular/services/config/EnvConfigurationService,js.erb

angular.module('mgApp.services').factory('EnvConfigurationService', function () {
return {
    getMySecretKey: function () {
        return "<%= ENV['MY_SECRET_KEY'] %>";
    }
  }
});
```

The intention is to provide access to 'MY_SECRET_KEY' from different angular and regular js classes. Like the following on userController.js:

```
angular.module('mgApp.controllers').controller('userController', ['$scope', '$http', 'EnvConfigurationService', function($scope, $http, EnvConfigurationService) {
  var uri = EnvConfigurationService.getMySecretKey();
  ...
}]);
```

Still, the returned string is always empty. Any ideas what might be wrong/missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This website shows 4 great ways to pass info from Rails to Angular](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/11/22/pass-rails-data-angularjs/)

Option number 3 states that if you are going to use interpolation like that, you may need to call `.html_safe` like shown in this example.

```
itemsApp.service('itemsAppInitializer', function(){
  return <%= @item.to_json.html_safe %>;
});
```

In my opinion, there could be one other way that you could tackle this issue if you wanted to. I would create a route in rails that returns env variables to you in the response.

Then whenever the service needs to provide env variables for the first time, you can use `$http.get()` with the `cache: true` option added in your service call to fetch that data from the route/controller, and only need to fetch it once.

Comment: Adding html_safe made it, @Sean Larking. Thanks!

Comment: :-D Enjoy. That props to that article as well.