# How to inject value of ENV variable into Angular template?

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, environment-variables

In my web app when I inspect HTML of billing page on Heroku - form's `action` attribute **is empty**, but on my local machine (in development and in production mode) it correctly points to a value of ENV['TWOCHECKOUT_PURCHASE_URL'] variable.

Form's `action` attribute must contain different URLs depending on environment Rails is running. How to make it work?

**application.yml**

```
TWOCHECKOUT_PURCHASE_URL: 'https://sandbox.2checkout.com/checkout/purchase'
```

**home.html.erb**

```
<sb-billing></sb-billing>
```

**sbBillingDirective.js.erb**

```
//= depend_on_asset "billing_directive.html"

(function() {

    angular
        .module('scrumban.widgets')
        .directive('sbBilling', billingDirective);

    function billingDirective() {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {},
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: '<%= asset_path("billing_directive.html") %>',
            controller: BillingController,
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        }
    }

    BillingController.$inject = ['$scope', 'BillingService', '_'];
    function BillingController($scope, BillingService, _) {
      // not relevant code
    }
```

**billing_directive.html.erb**

```
<form id="2checkout" 
      action="<%= ENV['TWOCHECKOUT_PURCHASE_URL'] %>"
      method="post">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found anwer here:
[Access Rails env variable from Angular Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33740536/access-rails-env-variable-from-angular-controller)

After I added `.html_safe` it worked:

```
<form id="2checkout" 
      action="<%= ENV['TWOCHECKOUT_PURCHASE_URL'].html_safe %>"
      method="post">
</form>
```